# SSJS script activity not updating Query Definition as expected

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, sql, ssjs

I am trying to update a query definition in Marketing cloud using SSJS script which updates the query based on the datestamp. When I run the script, I don't get any error but it does not seem to be updating the query definition for some reason. The script is below:

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
var qd = QueryDefinition.Init("37af1441-0b0c-4f99-b8ac-ac511da5ff2c");
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate()+1;

var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var year = yyyy.toString();
var yy = year.substring(2);
var send_date = (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + (today.getDate() + 1) + "-" + yy;
var str1 = "]";
var dename = "10-ControlGroup-MyWeekend-" + yyyy + mm + dd + str1;
var sql = "Select A.EmailAddress as Email, 2 as [Campaign ID], 1 as [Control Group],'" + send_date + " 12:00:00 AM' as [Send Date], B.[Janrain ID] as [Janrain ID] FROM [" + dename + " A INNER JOIN [Subscribers] B on A.EmailAddress = B.EmailAddress" ; 
var status = qd.Update({
    Name : "Control Group - Query to Populate MyWeekend History Log - UPDATED",

    QueryText : sql
    });
qd.Perform();
</script>
```

Would anyone know why it might not be working as expected? Thanks for your help in advance.

Cheers,
Gaurav

Comment: Is there any updates at all to the query, or is it exactly the same regardless of what you put in your script? Have you output your variables and Qry text in a cloudpage to verify they are correctly formed? Have you output the returned status code from your update function? Please provide more info and we should be able to provide better debugging help.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington, thanks for your reply. I just outputted the variable sql in Cloudpages and can verify it is correct! And answer to your first question, there is no updates at all to the query definition. How to return the status code from the update function? I have not done this before, can you please advise?

Comment: You just output the var you used to declare the update (`status`). So something like `Write(Stringify(status))`

Comment: Hi @Gortonington, thanks for that. I am getting "error" in cloudpages. But there is no additional details. Do you know what kind of error this might be? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Might need to use full Stringify function (`Platform.Function.Stringify()`)

Comment: @Gortonington, I am getting a blank response now, the error has gone away. Do you know what a blank response means?

Comment: if you are using `Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(status))` and it is not returning `OK` or an error message then there is something likely wrong with the syntax of your code. This function should always return a value when run. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_queryDefinitionUpdate.htm

Comment: @Gortonington, thanks the code is working now. I did not realise earlier that the variable was only pulling as single digit '5' whereas the name of the DE had double digits '05" which I have fixed and the code is working as intended now. Thanks for your help suggestions, it helped me to troubleshoot the issue. Cheers!